# Seconds and scale_x_time - HH:MM instead of HH:MM:SS

Tags: r, datetime, ggplot2, scale, seconds

Input data is structured like

| Price | Seconds | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11111 | 6443 | 2022-01-03 |
| 22222 | 7400 | 2022-01-04 |

```
ggplot(data=d.2,aes(x=Seconds, y=Price)) + 
  geom_path(colour="blue") + 
  ylab("Price") + 
  xlab("Date") +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(7*3600+5*60, 15*3600+25*60)) +
  facet_wrap(~Date, nrow = 1) +
  scale_x_time()
```

Right now I got the following output

[image]

Tried manipulating the scale_x_time in some ways I found on here, but can't seem to get it right.

I would like to display time of the day just in hours and minutes, such that it fits my lowre x axis better.

Comment: Could you edit your question to be minimally reproducible? Two lines of data are unfortunately insufficient. If you need some tips, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Under the hood `scale_x_time` converts your seconds to a `hms` object. Unfortunately I have not found an option to format an `hms` to show only the hours and minutes directly. But one option would be to convert to a datetime  first:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union

d.2 <- data.frame(
  Price = c(11111L, 22222L),
  Seconds = c(6443L, 7400L),
  Date = c("2022-01-03", "2022-01-04")
)

ggplot(data = d.2, aes(x = Seconds, y = Price)) +
  geom_path(colour = "blue") +
  ylab("Price") +
  xlab("Date") +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(7 * 3600 + 5 * 60, 15 * 3600 + 25 * 60)) +
  facet_wrap(~Date, nrow = 1) +
  scale_x_time(
    labels = \(x) format(as_datetime(x, tz = "UTC"), "%H:%M")
  )
#> `geom_path()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
#> `geom_path()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
```

[image]